# Text box mirror text

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Using PowerPoint 2013, I have a text box with some text in it.

I would like to apply a mirror effect to the text box, so that the text is a mirror image of the default. I tried <kbd>Rotate</kbd> <kbd>Flip Horizontal</kbd>, however it seems to have no effect.

How can I do this?

Comment: I googled this and found many answers that all point to the msoffice wordart functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Right click the text box
- Format Shape
- In the panel that opens (typically on right side of screen), click the pentagon icon for "effects"
- Expand the "3-D Rotation" group
- Change the "X Rotation" to 180

Answer (score 0):

Select the text box (ie, you should see selection handles)
Press Ctrl+C or choose to Copy it.
Use Paste Special, choose PNG as the paste type.
Drag the upper middle selection handle of the PNG downwards until it's as far below the bottom of the PNG as it originally was above it.

Voila.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but does not allow the text to be modified once flipped.

Comment: Your comment is technically correct but in fact, the text is not modifiable once pasted as PNG, whether or not it's flipped.  ;-)

Comment: I tip my hat to you sir

Comment: And I to you, sir.  ;-)